# Bootstrap Collapse inside for loop in ejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, ejs

This is the ejs file code. The collapse is not working .Can u please help me?

```
<% for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){%>
<div id="content">
<p><%=data[i].webTitle%></p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="collapseOne"+<%i%> aria-expanded="false">
    Button with data-target
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseOne"+<%i%> >
    <div class="card card-body">
        <p><%=data[i].fields.bodyText%></p>
    </div>
</div>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues there:

1. To concat the index to your id in ejs you should use **<%= variable =>** (fix in two places), example:

   ```
    "concatIndex<%= i %>"
   ```
2. If you want to collapse an item by ID, use **"#idToCollapse"** (fix in one place), example:

   ```
    "#selectorNumber<%=variable %>"
   ```

With those fixes, it should work. Don't forget to add bootstrap and jQuery to your project.

Comment: I tried your example with my suggestions and it works. Another suggestion, check the html generated in developer tools (f12).